# iron-ajax bind and write JSON to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, iron-ajax

I have the following iron-ajax element in my html:

```
<iron-ajax
  id="write-tweets"
  body='[{"statuses": "{{tweets}}"}]'
  url="/fscall"
  handle-as="json">
</iron-ajax>
```

And I have this in the js file for the above html:

```
Polymer({
is: "sample-app",

properties: {
  tweets: {
    type: Object,
    value: [],
  },
},

handleResponse(e){
  console.log("_________Twitter responses aquired:_________");
  this.tweets = this.tweets.concat(e.detail.response.statuses);
  this.writeTweets();
},
```

At this point, `tweets` is an array of JSON objects:

[image]

Now I'm trying to send this back to the node.js server so I can write/save it to a file.

```
writeTweets(){
  let ajax = this.root.querySelector('#write-tweets');
  ajax.generateRequest();  
}
... //some unrelated code
```

I have the following in app.js:

```
app.get('/fscall', (req, res) => {  
  fs.writeFile("tweets.json", JSON.parse(req.body, null, 4), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

And here I'm running into errors, I have no idea how to access the JSON that I sent, `req.body` seems to be empty. Same happens if I try to wrap `tweets` in a getter (e.g. doing `{returnTweets(){ return this.tweets;},` and `body='[{"statuses": "{{returnTweets()}}"}]'`.

Can anyone advise on how I could pass the JSON and print it?

**UPDATE**

OK so I'm managing to bind the tweets to the `body` of the request by doing

```
<iron-ajax
  method="POST"
  id="write-tweets"
  body$='{"statuses": {{tweetsParsed}}}'
  url="/fscall"
  handle-as="json">
</iron-ajax>
```

Where `tweetsParsed` is a property that contains the `JSON.stringify`ed tweets. Now if I check the ajax request, it contains the tweets in the body:

[image]

HOWEVER, I'm still not getting anything on the server side, and console. logging `request.body` returns `{}`... Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you confirm that json was send to server (via chrome dev tools)?
2. Dont use iron-ajax its buggy as hell try [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is nativly supported by your browser
3. If you actually send your json to the backend it should be in `request.body.statuses`

Comment: I updated the question - I've managed to properly bind the tweets, but it's not being sent to the server. I'm pretty sure this should work with `iron-ajax` so I'd rather not add any external libraries.

Comment: Mh honestly i´m still clueless. Maybe it is because from the client you send a post request but expect a get in your app.js? Can you see the body of the request containing the tweets in the dev tools of your browser? Can you post more code of your app.js file?